# Why does this 'eloquent Javascript' recursive solution work?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm working through Eloquent Javascript, the exercise asks to find a recursive solution for finding the nth element in a nested list of this form;

```
var list = {
   value: 1, 
   rest: {
     value: 2, 
     rest: {
       value: 3,
       rest: null
     }
   }
};
```

After scratching my head over this for far too long I duly checked the answer.

```
function nth(list, n) {
  if (!list)
    return undefined;
  else if (n == 0)
    return list.value;
  else
    return nth(list.rest, n - 1);
```

I can see that this does indeed produce the right result but I do not understand why.

**My understanding of the logic is as follows**

If no list is provided or list is falsey, return undefined,
else if n is 0, then return the first element of the list - which is given by list.value. 
Else call the function again but decrement n by 1.

Clearly I must be missing something but I do not understand how this logic can return the nth element. It seems like it will just keep recursing until n==0. At which point it will simply return the first element of the list.

Comment: Have you actually tried running through the code with a small, sample list?  Does it actually run to `n == 0` like you think it does?

Comment: Notice, that recursive calls are passing `list.rest`, not the whole `list`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f8vgm803/2/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical functional style linked list iteration. Notice that the recursive call goes on `list.rest`, not on `list` again. `list.rest` is the list that starts with the next element. In procedural style, the equivalent to taking the list's rest would be to increment an index pointer.

The beauty of that style is that you describe in code a property of lists : *the nth element of a list L is also the (n-1)th element of the list that starts past L's head*. Getting closer to a declarative form can sometimes make it easier to verify the correctness of what you write.

A downside of the style appears in the case of a large list, where such a function will run into a deep recursion that a Javascript engine most likely can't handle. Compilers/interpreters dedicated to functional languages would eliminate that recursion if possible, transforming it into a loop, a transformation called "tail call optimisation". TCO, freeing the developer from the constraints that come when you're bound to a stack, allows functional languages to use recursion as a main way of iterating, and thus in that world you see and write such constructs all over the place.

Comment: In other words, by the time `n` gets to `0`, `list`s first element is the one you want - you always return the first element of a given subset of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

This statement also made me think well. i have finally figured it out so i feel i should add to the previous answer.

the "n-1" statement in the  nth(list.rest, n - 1) is essentially a timer that determines when the programme should terminate. remember when it gets to 0 it returns the value as per this statement.

```
 else if (n == 0)
    return list.value;
```

so for example a list is passed into your function
 "{ Value: 1, Rest: { Value: 2, Rest: { Value: 3, Rest: null } } }"
 You pass in 2 as the argument.
 it calls the function and goes through the if statements then gets to the recursive statement. it calls List.Rest and then decreases the value of your passed in argument by 1. 
It repeats the cycle above and gets to the recursive function where what gets passed is now List.Rest.Rest your argument decreases by 1 again and it becomes 0 . 
When it passes through the if and else if statement , because the argument is now 0 the below line gets triggered

```
else if (n == 0)
    return list.value;
```

it then returns the list. value.... remember that your list is now list.Rest.Rest
making your value now 3.